# db INDEX on ORDER BY FIELD in very simple query does not help - still slow response?

Tags: index, db2, order-by, sorting

I have very simple query which returns 200K records very slow (20 seconds).

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC
```

If I do just

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

it returns quick result.

I created INDEX on that field ID (ALLOW REVERSE SCANS) but still returns very similar response. Where can be the problem? What can be the cause of stagnation for this query? I updated statictics and index table metadata.

Shouldn't INDEX help me on this ORDER BY FIELD?

My server has 8GB RAM.
Buffer pool has value of 128MB. I adjusted it to 1 GB but still no too much progress.

I am using DB2 database.

Configuration Parameters are with this values: (SORTHEAP) = AUTOMATIC(164) and (SHEAPTHRES_SHR) = AUTOMATIC(824).  (SHEAPTHRES) = 0. Should I maybe adjust them and on what values?

This is live system in production so I will be very thankful for help.

Thank you

Comment: I dont know anything about db2, but assuming it is similar to SQL Server, did you try a clustered index instead of a non clustered index (since you are using a select * query)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all a `SELECT *` will pretty much void using any indexes. DB2 will see that you require the entire table and thus do a table scan (which in itself can be expensive).

After that you are doing a an `ORDER BY`, which causes DB2 to do a `SORT` on the table it just scanned (another expensive operation). So you have two expensive operations one after the other.

Another thing.....if ID is the primary key...it already built an index for you under the covers. (which again it will ignore with a `SELECT *`). So you now have a second index that is probably just taking up disk space. (Just as an fyi any field that has a unique constraint-including the primary key-DB2 automatically builds a unique index for you.)

So first off, what this really speaks to is a bad query (no other way to put it). Do you have any predicates to add to the SQL? If you can cut down what you are selecting with a `WHERE` clause, or if you don't need every column in the `SELECT`, then you could build an index or indexes over those columns and that would help.

I would advise you to do an `EXPLAIN` over this query so you can see the cost and the query plan that DB2 used. Then as you test out indexes, etc, you can see if DB2 chooses to take advantage of them or not, and which is the most efficient method.

Comment: Hi,  thansk for response. ID is not primary column so DB does not already have created index for that field- I checked it. Unofortunalety I can not change query it must begin with SELECT * (this is some IBM Maximo appliction and this is in some List tab where by default it starts with SELECT * and trust me it can not be changed). SELECT * is executred quite fast but my customer wants to have ORDER BY ID DESC so to be able to see immediately new records in list tab. I understand what you are talking but this is only 200K records and for this powerfull DB2 database it should be exucuted fast

Comment: But query is not bad - it is the most simpel and most logic query- show me all records (which I can filter on List tab how I want) order firstly by new ones. This is not bad query definetly. I run EXPLAIN but it shows me that it is using index on some other fields (some ield STATUS and CLASS). Like it is using the wrong index - why and how to change it?? I have index for ID only but it is using other index. Also are my configuration paramteres and buffer pool set adequately? Thank you for effort and answers

Comment: Yeah...other IBM products do tend to use the SELECT * thing, which kills performance after a while. The hard thing is a SELECT * will mean a LOT of disk I/O for you (at least the first time and depending on if it stays in your buffer pool). The ORDER BY will cause a SORT, which will probably cause more I/O in your temporary tablespace. Again, do an EXPLAIN over the query. It will show you the truth of what DB2 is doing. Other things to take into consideration: are you at the latest fix packs? Can you call IBM about the Maximo issue? Maybe they can fix on their end_it"s their product after all.

Comment: Hi, I noticed one more thing. When I do SELECT * it is executed quite fast. If I execute SELECT * ORDER BY ID it is executed quite long but I noticed that IBM Maximo application is calling in behind SELECT COUNT(*) which is also executed quite fast. How is this possible - to SELECT * is executed quite fast and SELECT COUNT(*) is executed slowly. I do not think it stays in buffers(caches) becuase I run it shortly after my first query situation i same- why does not stays in buffer pool?? Do you have maybe explaination for that? On what size I should then set buffer pool (currently 1GB)?? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for lots of my questions and really thank you for your help, I am not db expert so I am totally confused. Important for me is why if BUFFER POOL is 1 GB it does not stay in buffer pool and why is such big difference between SELECT * and SELECT COUNT(*) . Can I have some impact on that?? Thank you!

Comment: I am with latest fix pack : 9.7.0.7 and I opened PMR in IBM - all that they said to me is RUNSTATS, REORG and similar which I did and my statistics does see that index but it is not using correct one

Comment: Have you done an EXPLAIN yet on it?

Comment: `SELECT * ` is fast because DB2 can just start scanning the table and returning rows.  `SELECT COUNT(*)` is fast because DB2 can scan an index very quickly to get a row count.  `SELECT * ... ORDER BY` is slow because DB2 has to fetch and sort the entire table.

Comment: I did EXPLAIN on ORDER BY and it is somehow using some other index which is reffering to some other columns which is very strange..I don't know, thank you for help but I am tottally confused..Is it possible that this powerfull IBM application which uses many,many,many big companies in the world with this powerfull IBM database is not able to do SELECT * ORDER BY ID faster than 20 seconds on just 200000 rows???? As I understood you both nothing can be done to improve perrormance???? There is something that I can do for sure--Buffer pool is on 1 GB, I set SORTHEAP on automatic..what  can I do?:(

Comment: Also I mistyped ti I meant that even SELECT COUNT(*) is returned very slow 10 seconds but SELECT * is returned very fast.. I meant on that.. What can be my other steps? I know that people are working with 10 milions o records but I am struggling with only 200K. How can I see where is my stangation? It can be normal for database to return this so slow

Comment: @Dejan - no DB2 can handle huge loads. The trick is trying to understand what the optimizer is doing. This is why you do the explain. DB2's optimizer will choose different paths to the data based on things like accurate RUNSTATS, indexes (or lack thereof), optimizer level (usually defaulted to 5 which should be fine), whether or not your table is partioned (or not), whether your table is an MDC or not, etc. It also takes into account things like ORDER BY, predicates, and what is selected (ie, * vs specific columns). So there is nothing to despair about.

Comment: @Dejan - the tick is understanding what DB2 is doing and why, and then deciding how you can obtain better behavior. One trick is to tell DB2 what you want, not what you don't want (that should be the case with any DBMS). Doing a select * may be what you want. But it can also be inefficient. If you have no predicates and a large volume, then you start running the risk of DB2 ignoring indexes since it sees that you want everything. This is why I tried to encourage you to change the query. Also if you use the FETCH N ROWS ONLY, that will help as DB2 will retrieve fewer rows.

Comment: Since you are using Maximo....I guess you are kind of stuck with what you have. However there are still a few things to try. You could try to remove the other indexes and see what happens. Perhaps that will nudge DB2 to use your other one. (But test this as those indexes may be needed elsewhere). You could also try table partitioning. That may help (no promises) but it would divide out the retrieval of the data. Of course you have to pay the price of your ORDER BY at some point...so the partitioning may or may not help you there.

Comment: If you are using SAN for your disk, you could also look at ways to tuning your retrieve times. Perhaps you have too much time on disk (which you can have even with temp tablespace usage). Or even look into seeing if there is a patch or newer version of Maximo. Perhaps they optimized how it generates SQL. Don't despair of DB2. That isn't your problem. It is just trying to better get at what you want that you need.